# Mapstruct constructor injection (spring)

Tags: mapstruct

In mapstruct `1.3.0.Final` we have dependency injection via constructor. Documentation says:

> The generated mapper will inject all classes defined in the **uses**
>   attribute
>
> (...)
>
> For abstract classes or decorators setter injection should be
>   used.

I have following example:

```
@Mapper
public abstract class VehicleMapper {

    @Autowired
    private CarMapper carMapper;
    @Autowired
    private BikeMapper bikeMapper;

    @Override
    public VehicleDTO toDto(final Vehicle source) {

        if (source instanceof Car) {
            return carMapper.toDto((Car) source);
        } else if (source instanceof Bike) {
            return bikeMapper.toDto((Bike) source);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    (...)
```

So in my case it should look like this (`componentModel` defined in maven):

```
@Mapper
public abstract class VehicleMapper {

    private CarMapper carMapper;
    private BikeMapper bikeMapper;

    @Autowired
    public void setCarMapper(final CarMapper carMapper) {
        this.carMapper = carMapper;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBikeMapper(final BikeMapper bikeMapper) {
        this.bikeMapper = bikeMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public VehicleDTO toDto(final Vehicle source) {

        if (source instanceof Car) {
            return carMapper.toDto((Car) source);
        } else if (source instanceof Bike) {
            return bikeMapper.toDto((Bike) source);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
    (...)
```

**Question:**
So it is not possible to inject `carMapper` and `bikeMapper` via constructor ? does `injectionStrategy = CONSTRUCTOR` works only for classes declared in `@Mapper(uses = {})` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `injectionStrategy = CONSTRUCTOR` works on the interface that has the `@Mapper` annotation. I don't think it works with abstract classes. I'm sure it will not work when you define your own fields (instance variables). How would MapStruct know what user defined fields to initialise in the constructor?

Comment: @umi0410 there is a feature request for it here https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2257

Comment: Thanks. I used gradle compile option.